# Why scripts don't work when I click on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a button which when user click on it, phone numbers will be appear slowly.

Here is the HTML Codes:

```
<span id="show-phone-numbers" class="btn btn-success">
   <i class="fe fe-phone-call"></i> Show Phone Number
</span> 

<div class="media margin-top-20" id="phone-number-section" style="display:none">
    <div class="media-body text-center">

         <a href="tel:00000000">
             <p class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                  <i class="fe fe-phone-call"></i>    somephonenumber
             </p>
         </a>
                                                    

         <a href="tel:00000000">
             <p class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                  <i class="fe fe-phone-call"></i>    somephonenumber
             </p>
         </a>
                                                
     </div>
</div>
```

And here is the scripts:

```
$("#show-phone-numbers").on("click",function(){
    $("#phone-number-section").toggle("slow");
});
```

The problem is **when I click** on the "Show Phone Number" button, nothing happens, even in console I see nothing happening

I did search about the error but I couldn't find a way which help me to handle this error.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you loaded jquery properly before bootstrap?

Comment: @Esszed - From top to button:  jquery.min.js -> propper.min.js -> bootstrap-rtl.js

Comment: Let's recap. You had an error, so you're ok checking the console for errors.   Your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/qyb13vsn/) as presented.  The most likely issue is that your code is running before the HTML exists.  Wrap your code in `$(() => { ... });` doc ready or move your code to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Mmh.. `.toggle("slow");`? Did you mean `.toggle("show");` or is this just a typo in your question? BTW you can make your code work directly in StackOverflow with the `<>` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `data-bs-toggle="tab"` in there, without any bootstrap tab elements? This causes the BS event handler to be registered, which throws this error, because it can't find properly setupped tabs.

Comment: Thank you, I removed it and the error is gone now. but I have now a new problem, nothing happens when I click on the button now.